# Data population is not happening in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

As I am new to DocuSign Apis. I am having an issue with predata populating in DocuSign template while sending an email also when I add dynamic recipients from my code template fields are going as blank instead of appending data and sending to the user.Please, can anyone help me on this?

Below is my code:

```
<?php
// Input your info here:
$name = "";
$email = '';
$integratorKey = '';
$password = '';
$email1 = 'testmail@gmail.com';
$templateId = "826e138e-7ad6-4ceb-853b-f545be643527";

$header = "<DocuSignCredentials>
    <Username>" . $email . "</Username>
    <Password>" . $password . "</Password>
    <IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"
));
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($status != 200)
{
echo "Error  calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

$data = array(
    "accountId" => $accountId,
    "emailSubject" => "DocuSign Templates Webinar - Example 2",
    "emailBlurb" => "Example #2 - Dynamically Populate Form Fields",
    "templateId" => $templateId,
    "templateRoles" => array(
        array(
            "email" => $email,
            "name" => $name,
            "roleName" => "Developer",
            "tabs" => array(
                "textTabs" => array(
                    array(
                        "tabLabel" => "ApplicantSSN",
                        "value" => "test test456456"
                    ) ,
                )
            )
        )
    ) ,
    "status" => "sent"
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string) ,
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"
));
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json_response);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($status != 201){
    print_r($json_response);
    echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

// To add recipients in docusign
$data1 = json_encode(array(
    "signers" => array(
        array(
            "email" => $email1,
            "name" => 'jkl',
            "roleName" => "Signer",
            "recipientId" => 5000
        )
    )
));
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes/" . $envelopeId . "/recipients");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data1) ,
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data1);
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
?>
```

Comment: This worked for me after the Docusign support team.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps and above code it will work as expected.

1.Login to your Demo Account
2.Remove the recipient name and email for the role leaving just the role name.